# MongoDB return last entry by date

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to return the last entry in my mongodb database. I have two different collections I need to perform this function on. I wrote the following to perform this task.

```js
//Located in my Mongoose Model
module.exports.returnSingleRet = function(query, callback){
  return inspections.findOne(query,function(err, item){
    if (err) throw err;
    return item;
  });
}

//Located in script looking for last entry
var last = await Inspections.returnSingleRet({project_id: 
projects[p].id},null,{sort: {date: -1}});
```

This code worked perfectly for the first data set. It had over 15,000 entries. When I run on my second collection 1,500 items. It always returns my first entry in the collection?? The field I am sorting by in both collections are iso dates..

Comment: No it did not work perfectly at all. You are passing **three** arguments to your `returnSingleRet` function, but it only accepts **two** arguments, with the second being the callback. And you are not waiting for a callback, you are waiting for a "Promise".

Comment: What you mean to do is `query = [{ {project_id: 
projects[p].id, null, { sort: { date: -1 } }]; var last = await Inspections.findOne(...query);` And I'm not sure whose teaching people these days to create superfluous methods for simply passing trivial arguments ( ie `retSingleSet` does not alter `findOne` at all ) but they probably should be teaching you language syntax instead.

Comment: Niel thanks! I appreciate your help.